# How is the power per unit angle of an antenna infinite?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

In my homework the **power per solid angle** (or however you call it) $\dfrac{\mathrm{dP}}{\mathrm{d\Omega}}$ of an $\texttt{antenna}$

> $\texttt{antenna:}$ $\textsf{just a wire of length L in z-direction with current density $j_\omega = I_0\,\sin(k\,L-k\,r)\,\delta(x)\,\delta(y)\,\hat{e}_z$} $

is given by the following formula:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{dP}}{d\,\Omega} = C\cdot I_0\left(\dfrac{\cos(k\,L\,\cos(\theta))-\cos(k\,L)}{\sin(\theta)}\right)^2$$

where $\theta$ is the polar angle.

I was supposed to plot this quantity in a polar plot depending on $\theta$, but as you might have sensed already, dividing by $\sin(\theta)$ is not ending well ($\to \infty$).

I only get useful results, multiplying with $\sin(\theta)$ but this is not what the power per solid angle is looking like. So how can this phenomena of infinit power be interpreted in the first place?

Comment: Actually you’ll notice that the numerator has zero limit as well, which cancels the infinity of the denominator. More precisely, as $\theta\to0$ you have:$$\sin\theta\sim\theta \\ \cos(kL\cos\theta)-\cos(kL)\sim -\sin(kL)\frac{(kL\theta)^2}{2} \\
\frac{dP}{d\Omega}\sim CI_0\left(\frac{\sin(kL)(kL)^2\theta}{2}\right)^2$$ so in particular it cancels at $0$.

Comment: What a surprise! Actually my plotting function had a little confusion in it, but thanks to your comment I doublechecked and spotted the wrongly placed bracket. Totally worth a tick-mark.